# Creating a tableview from a xib view and swift file and populating from another file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I'm still fairly new to swift, and I'm trying to create a tableview in a xib, attaching it to a swift file, but then I want to populate it using another swift file. I also have have another xib for the custom table cell. What I am trying right now does not work.

A section of the ViewController class:

```
    var testArray = ["test", "test1","test2","test3","test4"]

    var pages : [dataViewController]{
        get {
            let page1: dataViewController = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("dataView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! dataViewController
            page1.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)
            page1.tookClassTable.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "tookClassCell")
            page1.tookClassTable.delegate = self
            page1.tookClassTable.dataSource = self

            return [page1]
        }
    }

    // TableView functions

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tookClassCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.tookClassCell.text = testArray[indexPath.row]
        print(testArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell

    }
```

Basically, I made a paging type view, such as the iOS home screen, and have page1 and page2. In page1, there is a tableView, and registered the tableViewCell and used cellForRowAt to try to populate the table. There are no errors, but the table is just blank.

[image: no table]

Does anyone know how to populate this tableView? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you forget to implement UITableViewDataSource?

Comment: @CharlieCai, No, I added UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate to the class, and set page1.delegate and dataSource = self

Comment: can you set cell height and try?

Comment: @CharlieCai, I set heightForRowAt to 50.0 and ran it, nothing changed.

Comment: I notice you are using different cell identifier when register and dequeue. "tookClassCell" and "customCell".try use the same identifier

Comment: @CharlieCai, oh, I seem to have forgot to set the cell identifier. But the program still ran without populating the table.